# A train is moving up an incline of inclination $\pi/6$ with constant velocity. A bob is hung on the ceiling. The angle made by the bob with normal?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, forces

Mass of bob is 1 kilogram.
Let the angle of Bob with the normal be $\phi$ the force acting on bob along the axis of motion is 
$$mg\cos(\phi)$$ 
Now as this train is having zero acceleration, bob must move with zero acceleration so the force acting on bob due to gravity ie $$mg\sin(\pi/6)$$ 
Therefore $mg\sin(\pi/6) = mg\cos(\phi)$
Then phi must be $\pi/3$ but the answer my book has is different.  What's the mistake I'm making?

Answer (score 4):

There is no acceleration so it does not matter whether or not the train is moving.
Draw a Free body diagram for the bob.
The answer should be staring you in the face.